# the active editor cannot provide timeline information

Tags: editor

> How can I resolve this issue with my vscode 'the active editor cannot provide timeline information'

I tried to open files and folders on my vscode but all I see on the explorer is 'the active editor cannot provide timeline information'

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).